# Need assistance with RegEx using Perl and AutoHotKey

Tags: regex, perl, autohotkey

I'm trying to read specific values from a TestString using Perl and can't seem to get to where I need to.  Hoping someone could help me.

I'm trying to read the value that starts the string and only two numbers to the left of the decimal and save it to value1.  It has to be the value that ends two numbers to the left of the decimal and to the start of the string since the leading numbers may be 4, 3, or 2 numbers (e.g. 123420.78616 or 3320.78616).

So with the example below, I'm looking to save "133" to value1 using regexmatch and autohotkey.

The second regexmatch is, I need to save the other portion of the number to value2.  Value2 would start two numbers to the left of the decimal and then to the end of the string.  So I need the "20.78616" to be saved as value2.

Below I can only capture the full number with the Perl used and I've been trying combinations for hours with a regex101.com to no avail.

Hoping someone could help me.

```
TestString := "13320.78616"
RegExMatch (TestString, "(([\w\.]+)$)", value1)
RegExMatch (TestString, "(([\w\.]+)$)", value2)

msgbox, %value1%
msgbox, %value2%
```

Comment: Your description of what you'd like to match on is a bit unclear. Please add some real indata and the expected outcome.

Comment: Can divide by 100 and take int: `int($str/100)` (If it's always a number in that string)

Answer (score 1):

Suggest the following regex:

```
(\d+)(\d\d\.\d*)
```

Three things to note:

- use `\d` instead of `\w` if you want to capture just digits and not letters;
- the `(\d+)` captures a leading string of at least one digit, and ends two digits before the decimal because of the next part:
- the `(\d\d\.\d*)` captures exactly two digits, the decimal point, and any following digits.

Comment: So using (\d+)(\d\d\.\d*) doesn't get me the 133 = value1.  I instead get the full string 13320.78616.  Using (\d\d\.\d*) does get me 20.78616 = value2.  Any other suggestions on the first value?

Comment: I noticed when using regex101.com, it shows the 133 as a group1 match and the 20.78616 as a group2 match.  Not sure how to handle the different groups...

Comment: I got it - figured out how to get the groups in autohotkey.  SImply adding the number to the end of the value did it.  Thanks for your help!